# Acronyms and Slang

Tags: discussion

Is there a central location where the various acronyms used on this site are defined?  I was reading a post today which referenced SOLID (which I recognized). It then used SRP (able to find searching wikipedia).  The rest of the post and several answers then contained:

- IoC
- OP
- KISS
- CRC
- ORM
- DTO
- DAO
- IMO

I recognize some, can guess at others, and am completely lost on the rest.

Comment: Perhaps this can be a suggestion for the blog team?

Comment: post that referenced SOLID would better be marked with [`solid` tag](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tags/solid/info "just take a look at the tag wiki!") - this is a standard magic at Stack Exchange to help with frequently used acronyms

Comment: @gnat Not necessarily, questions that are about SOLID, yes, but just reference SOLID in some way, no.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computing_and_IT_abbreviations

Comment: @YannisRizos that list isn't very helpful half the technical terms the OP mentioned aren't listed

Comment: You forgot, `TL;DR` `IANAL` `IMHO` `IIRC` `AFAIK` and other common acronyms used in Q&A sites.

Comment: See also - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-overflow-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms

Answer (score 6):

<strike>No.</strike> Apparently there is on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-overflow-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)

As far as I know there aren't many acronyms that are specific to Stack Exchange (apart from the obvious use of site initials - e.g. SO for Stack Overflow).

Have you tried http://acronymfinder.com?

However, if someone uses an acronym in a post that you're not familiar with leave them a comment asking them to explain what it means. There are far too many of these TLAs* for us all to remember them all and some have multiple meanings.

*Three Letter Acronyms

Answer (score 6):

Some of the acronyms are widely recognizable programming terms:

- IoC = Inversion of Control
- KISS = Keep It Simple, Stupid!
- CRC = Cyclic Redundancy Check
- ORM = Object-Relational Mapping
- DTO = Data Transfer Object (I'll admit, I looked this one up)
- DAO = Data Access Object

And you should easily find out what they mean with a simple web search or in a reference source, like Wikipedia. The other two acronyms are indeed internet slang:

- OP = Original Poster
- IMO / IMHO = In My Opinion / In My Humble Opinion

Those may not be as easy to find, but shouldn't be very hard either, and you can always post a comment asking what the acronym means. Some other acronyms you'll see often on Programmers are:

- SE = Stack Exchange
- PSE / P.SE / Prog.SE / ProgSE = Programmers
- SO = Stack Overflow
- SU = Super User
- SF = Server Fault
- NC = Not Constructive
- NARQ = Not A Real Question
- OT = Off Topic
- FAQ = Frequently Asked Questions
- TL;DR = Too Long; Didn't Read
- IANAL = I Am Not A Lawyer
- IIRC = If I Recall Correctly
- AFAIK = As Far As I Know
- HTH = Hope That Helps

Comment: it might be worthwhile to make this a separate meta post with FAQ tagged

Comment: FAQ = frequently asked questions (SCNR)

Comment: @user281377 Be bold, edit ;P

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest that if you see an acronym that you don't understand, you should leave a comment asking for someone to edit it into the post. If you also see an acronym that you do understand but isn't defined previously in the post, I would recommend editing it in so that it's defined for people who might not recognize it. Not only will this make it easier to read the questions, but also help other people find relevant questions when searching.

Comment: You could ask: WIGNAATIH does ___ mean?